# How to sort data list into specific rows/columns using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list of 31,500 unique numbers.  I am needing to sort the list into chunks of 250 in each column for 4 columns and then cycle underneath the top 4 and repeat the process until the end of the list.

I have already tried and have been able to sort the list into columns only but not cycle underneath.

```
Sub ExportData(division As Integer)

    Dim cols As New Collection
    Dim rows As New Collection

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    Dim fileCounter As Integer
    fileCounter = 0

    Dim fileContent As String
    fileContent = ""

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from activity1")

    Set rows = New Collection

    While Not rs.EOF
        rows.Add rs("Field1").Value
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = division Then
            fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
            counter = 0
            cols.Add rows
            Set rows = New Collection
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    If counter > 0 Then
        fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
        counter = 0
        cols.Add rows
    End If

    Dim i_col As Integer
    Dim j_row As Integer
    Dim rowText As String

    For j_row = 1 To division
        For i_col = 1 To fileCounter
            On Error Resume Next
            If i_col = fileCounter Then
                rowText = rowText & cols(i_col)(j_row)
            Else
                rowText = rowText & cols(i_col)(j_row) & ","
            End If
        Next
        rowText = rowText & vbCrLf
    Next
End Sub
```

[Example of formatting I'm needing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9nR9.jpg)

Comment: also need to define division and give it a value (say 7 for testing now, but later probably a value of 250).  And there is nothing that defines colMax of 4, or which col is being handled, nor what should separate the 250x4 Chunks one from another.  More definition of expected output is needed.  Also, the columns will be WAVY depending on length of Field1 values.

Comment: Whoa, original problem said "in each column for 4 columns",  but now the ExampleOfFormatting has 8 columns A/thru/H across the top.  Please remove the confusion by editing one or the other.

Comment: Your requirement seems similar to https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=73256&page=2. However, printing 250 lines per page seems unfeasible, even to 11x17 page.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  You can change the vertical(maxChunk) or horizontal(maxCol) sizes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub doit()

    Dim rs As adodb.Recordset
    Set rs = New adodb.Recordset
    rs.Open "Select * From activity1 Order By Field1", CurrentProject.Connection, _
         adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    ' Inhale ALL of the records into an array (base zero)
    Dim varRecords As Variant, maxRecCnt As Long
    varRecords = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount, , "Field1") '(rs.RecordCount)
    maxRecCnt = UBound(varRecords, 2)

    Debug.Print maxRecCnt

    Dim x As Long
    ' expected output
    ' A     B   C   D   E   F   G   H
    ' 1     6   11  16  21  26  31  36
    ' 2     7   12  17  22  27  32  37
    ' 3     8   13  18  23  28  33  38
    ' 4     9   14  19  24  29  34  39
    ' 5     10  15  20  25  30  35  40
    '41

    Dim allText As String

    Dim maxChunk As Long, rowInChunk As Long, numChunk As Long
    maxChunk = 5
    rowInChunk = 0

    Dim maxCol As Long, numCol As Long
    maxCol = 8
    numCol = 0

    For numChunk = 1 To maxRecCnt / maxChunk * maxCol
            For rowInChunk = 1 To maxChunk

                    Dim rowText As String
                    rowText = ""
                    For numCol = 1 To maxCol
                        ' compute which cell in the array we want
                        x = ((numCol - 1) * maxChunk) + rowInChunk - 1 + ((numChunk - 1) * maxChunk * maxCol)
                        On Error Resume Next  ' widows at the end
                        rowText = rowText & vbTab & varRecords(0, x)
                    Next numCol

                    'MsgBox (rowText)
                    allText = allText & vbCrLf & rowText

            Next rowInChunk
            allText = allText & vbCrLf

    Next numChunk

    MsgBox (allText)

End Sub
```